# How to find the optimized or correct peaks

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have following graph

[image]

I am using python's scipy.signal.find_peaks to find the peaks. But I am not sure how do I do that. I did following :

```
per = np.percentile(x,[70])
peaks_control = findPeaks(x, per[0])
```

where x is the signal

> array([1.07541259e+09, 1.13851049e+09, 1.19241492e+09, 1.23706527e+09,
> 1.27240093e+09, 1.29836131e+09, 1.31217483e+09, 1.32037296e+09,
> 1.31908858e+09, 1.30896503e+09, 1.29216550e+09, 1.26958042e+09,
> 1.24561632e+09, 1.21202121e+09, 1.16869371e+09, 1.11054499e+09,
> 1.04006154e+09, 9.65663403e+08, 8.87706760e+08, 8.09340093e+08,
> 7.37568765e+08, 6.79736364e+08, 6.38576457e+08, 6.06062937e+08,
> 5.80650350e+08, 5.55089744e+08, 5.36334499e+08, 5.20236597e+08,
> 5.06529837e+08, 4.91825175e+08, 4.77937063e+08, 4.65475058e+08,
> 4.56520513e+08, 4.48393240e+08, 4.41944988e+08, 4.34822844e+08,
> 4.33688578e+08, 4.33451049e+08, 4.36256177e+08, 4.33553613e+08,
> 4.29191142e+08, 4.28492541e+08, 4.24465967e+08, 4.20074825e+08,
> 4.19935897e+08, 4.16652681e+08, 4.12419580e+08, 4.11747552e+08,
> 4.08801166e+08, 4.02351981e+08, 3.99620513e+08, 3.98716550e+08,
> 3.46023077e+08, 3.53969464e+08, 4.17131235e+08, 5.19363869e+08,
> 6.50956410e+08, 8.01530303e+08, 9.50162937e+08, 1.08249790e+09,
> 1.18242378e+09, 1.22732168e+09, 1.20123077e+09, 1.21067599e+09,
> 1.21556410e+09, 1.21272261e+09, 1.20310023e+09, 1.18692774e+09,
> 1.16694033e+09, 1.14330117e+09, 1.11635338e+09, 1.07947529e+09,
> 1.03222145e+09, 9.73427972e+08, 9.08558974e+08, 8.39966200e+08,
> 7.70457343e+08, 7.04976224e+08, 6.49436131e+08, 6.02085548e+08,
> 5.68915385e+08, 5.41638928e+08, 5.18758741e+08, 5.01973660e+08,
> 4.88766667e+08, 4.77643823e+08, 4.65681818e+08, 4.56193240e+08,
> 4.46851515e+08, 4.36135198e+08, 4.32282984e+08, 4.27913520e+08,
> 4.23408625e+08, 4.24119580e+08, 4.22399068e+08, 4.22415385e+08,
> 4.20193939e+08, 4.17638462e+08, 4.14822378e+08, 4.10636364e+08,
> 4.08388345e+08, 4.04844522e+08, 4.00571562e+08, 4.00841026e+08,
> 4.00764802e+08, 4.00432867e+08, 4.00336364e+08, 4.00724709e+08,
> 4.03048019e+08, 3.57437995e+08, 3.62371096e+08, 4.16658741e+08,
> 5.10148019e+08, 6.31750117e+08, 7.65175991e+08, 8.96832168e+08,
> 1.01666597e+09, 1.10373263e+09, 1.14380816e+09, 1.11629790e+09,
> 1.12228904e+09, 1.12378788e+09, 1.11974825e+09, 1.10812774e+09,
> 1.09125035e+09, 1.07033566e+09, 1.04667389e+09, 1.02016830e+09,
> 9.86036830e+08, 9.42176457e+08, 8.88900233e+08, 8.27962005e+08,
> 7.64362238e+08, 7.00755245e+08, 6.42390909e+08, 5.92395338e+08,
> 5.52426107e+08, 5.26319114e+08, 5.03317249e+08, 4.85524942e+08,
> 4.70421911e+08, 4.59389510e+08, 4.51644988e+08, 4.46288578e+08,
> 4.41076923e+08, 4.37533566e+08, 4.31993007e+08, 4.28625641e+08,
> 4.25406294e+08, 4.21161538e+08, 4.19049650e+08, 4.16719347e+08,
> 4.13124242e+08, 4.08404429e+08, 4.06154545e+08, 4.03386014e+08,
> 4.00980420e+08, 3.99442657e+08, 3.97792075e+08, 3.95606527e+08,
> 3.97922378e+08, 3.98345221e+08, 3.96253613e+08, 3.95703030e+08,
> 3.96108392e+08, 3.67136830e+08, 3.58382051e+08, 3.95844289e+08,
> 4.70853846e+08, 5.76629837e+08, 6.97682284e+08, 8.21169930e+08,
> 9.32588112e+08, 1.01885804e+09, 1.06315152e+09, 1.05128159e+09,
> 1.03944545e+09, 1.03769580e+09, 1.03132145e+09, 1.02008601e+09,
> 1.00327389e+09, 9.85387646e+08, 9.66403030e+08, 9.44620746e+08,
> 9.18596737e+08, 8.82269697e+08, 8.37750816e+08, 7.84877156e+08,
> 7.27590443e+08, 6.70183217e+08, 6.14567832e+08, 5.67404895e+08,
> 5.30862471e+08, 5.03108625e+08, 4.84348718e+08, 4.68116550e+08,
> 4.55809907e+08, 4.46616783e+08, 4.39725175e+08, 4.34323077e+08])

The peaks I get are adjacent to each other, as I can see that there is little bump in second, third and forth peak sites.
[image]

How should I calculate it and ignore such adjacent ones. To calculate the width, prominecne, etc I need to calculate the peaks. If I know it already I might be able to put some threshold.

Comment: If you're using `find_peaks` of `scipy` (see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) you can set `distance`. If you don't know the distance, you can perform a periodogram and set the 1st harmonic period as distance

Comment: I am new to this. can you please provide me some example

Answer (score 0):

As you asked in the comments, I'll provide you an example. Please note, this is only an example, an Exploratory Data Analysis is always needed to choose the best way to reach your goal.

So, let's create some noisy data

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, periodogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 100
a = np.linspace(1, .5, size)
x = np.linspace(0, 50, size)
np.random.seed(0)
y = a * np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(0, .1, size) + 5
```

[image]

now, let's try to find the peaks with `find_peaks` from `scipy.signal`

```
peaks = find_peaks(y)[0]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x[peaks], y[peaks], marker='o', ls='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

as you can see, there are some "wrong" peaks. We need to set `distance` argument in `find_peaks` (see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)).

Let us suppose that we don't know the distance between the peaks. In this case, we can see that the data are periodic. So we can find the period with a periodogram and use the period as distance in `find_peaks`

```
_f, _p = periodogram(y, nfft=2**6)
# calculate the sample rate of x
sample_rate = 1 / np.median(np.diff(x))
periods = 1 / _f[1:] / sample_rate
density = _p[1:] / _p[1:].max()
max_density_idx = density.argmax()

period = periods[max_density_idx]

plt.semilogx(periods, density)
plt.scatter(period, density[max_density_idx], color='r')
plt.title(f"period {period:.2f}")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now we can use the period as `distance` argument in `find_peaks`

```
peaks = find_peaks(y, distance=period)[0]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x[peaks], y[peaks], marker='o', ls='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

## update

In your specific case, it's a little bit different.

Define the signal (I'll call variables `X` and `Y`)

```
Y = np.array([1.07541259e+09, 1.13851049e+09, 1.19241492e+09, 1.23706527e+09, 1.27240093e+09, 1.29836131e+09, 1.31217483e+09, 1.32037296e+09, 1.31908858e+09, 1.30896503e+09, 1.29216550e+09, 1.26958042e+09, 1.24561632e+09, 1.21202121e+09, 1.16869371e+09, 1.11054499e+09, 1.04006154e+09, 9.65663403e+08, 8.87706760e+08, 8.09340093e+08, 7.37568765e+08, 6.79736364e+08, 6.38576457e+08, 6.06062937e+08, 5.80650350e+08, 5.55089744e+08, 5.36334499e+08, 5.20236597e+08, 5.06529837e+08, 4.91825175e+08, 4.77937063e+08, 4.65475058e+08, 4.56520513e+08, 4.48393240e+08, 4.41944988e+08, 4.34822844e+08, 4.33688578e+08, 4.33451049e+08, 4.36256177e+08, 4.33553613e+08, 4.29191142e+08, 4.28492541e+08, 4.24465967e+08, 4.20074825e+08, 4.19935897e+08, 4.16652681e+08, 4.12419580e+08, 4.11747552e+08, 4.08801166e+08, 4.02351981e+08, 3.99620513e+08, 3.98716550e+08, 3.46023077e+08, 3.53969464e+08, 4.17131235e+08, 5.19363869e+08, 6.50956410e+08, 8.01530303e+08, 9.50162937e+08, 1.08249790e+09, 1.18242378e+09, 1.22732168e+09, 1.20123077e+09, 1.21067599e+09, 1.21556410e+09, 1.21272261e+09, 1.20310023e+09, 1.18692774e+09, 1.16694033e+09, 1.14330117e+09, 1.11635338e+09, 1.07947529e+09, 1.03222145e+09, 9.73427972e+08, 9.08558974e+08, 8.39966200e+08, 7.70457343e+08, 7.04976224e+08, 6.49436131e+08, 6.02085548e+08, 5.68915385e+08, 5.41638928e+08, 5.18758741e+08, 5.01973660e+08, 4.88766667e+08, 4.77643823e+08, 4.65681818e+08, 4.56193240e+08, 4.46851515e+08, 4.36135198e+08, 4.32282984e+08, 4.27913520e+08, 4.23408625e+08, 4.24119580e+08, 4.22399068e+08, 4.22415385e+08, 4.20193939e+08, 4.17638462e+08, 4.14822378e+08, 4.10636364e+08, 4.08388345e+08, 4.04844522e+08, 4.00571562e+08, 4.00841026e+08, 4.00764802e+08, 4.00432867e+08, 4.00336364e+08, 4.00724709e+08, 4.03048019e+08, 3.57437995e+08, 3.62371096e+08, 4.16658741e+08, 5.10148019e+08, 6.31750117e+08, 7.65175991e+08, 8.96832168e+08, 1.01666597e+09, 1.10373263e+09, 1.14380816e+09, 1.11629790e+09, 1.12228904e+09, 1.12378788e+09, 1.11974825e+09, 1.10812774e+09, 1.09125035e+09, 1.07033566e+09, 1.04667389e+09, 1.02016830e+09, 9.86036830e+08, 9.42176457e+08, 8.88900233e+08, 8.27962005e+08, 7.64362238e+08, 7.00755245e+08, 6.42390909e+08, 5.92395338e+08, 5.52426107e+08, 5.26319114e+08, 5.03317249e+08, 4.85524942e+08, 4.70421911e+08, 4.59389510e+08, 4.51644988e+08, 4.46288578e+08, 4.41076923e+08, 4.37533566e+08, 4.31993007e+08, 4.28625641e+08, 4.25406294e+08, 4.21161538e+08, 4.19049650e+08, 4.16719347e+08, 4.13124242e+08, 4.08404429e+08, 4.06154545e+08, 4.03386014e+08, 4.00980420e+08, 3.99442657e+08, 3.97792075e+08, 3.95606527e+08, 3.97922378e+08, 3.98345221e+08, 3.96253613e+08, 3.95703030e+08, 3.96108392e+08, 3.67136830e+08, 3.58382051e+08, 3.95844289e+08, 4.70853846e+08, 5.76629837e+08, 6.97682284e+08, 8.21169930e+08, 9.32588112e+08, 1.01885804e+09, 1.06315152e+09, 1.05128159e+09, 1.03944545e+09, 1.03769580e+09, 1.03132145e+09, 1.02008601e+09, 1.00327389e+09, 9.85387646e+08, 9.66403030e+08, 9.44620746e+08, 9.18596737e+08, 8.82269697e+08, 8.37750816e+08, 7.84877156e+08, 7.27590443e+08, 6.70183217e+08, 6.14567832e+08, 5.67404895e+08, 5.30862471e+08, 5.03108625e+08, 4.84348718e+08, 4.68116550e+08, 4.55809907e+08, 4.46616783e+08, 4.39725175e+08, 4.34323077e+08])

X = np.arange(Y.size)
```

Since `Y.size` is 200 and in your plot there are 200 secs, I assume that the sample rate is 1 sec.

If we search for the peaks with default distance we find a lot of unwanted peaks

```
peaks = find_peaks(Y)[0]
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.plot(X[peaks], Y[peaks], marker='o', ls='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Let's do a periodogram

```
_f, _p = periodogram(Y, nfft=2**12)
# the sample rate of your signal
sample_rate = 1 
periods = 1 / _f[1:] / sample_rate
density = _p[1:] / _p[1:].max()
max_density_idx = density.argmax()

period = periods[max_density_idx]

p_peaks_idx = find_peaks(density)[0]

plt.semilogx(periods, density)
plt.scatter(period, density[max_density_idx], color='r')
period_peaks = []
for p_peak in p_peaks_idx:
    if density[p_peak] < .1:
        continue
    period_peaks.append(periods[p_peak])
    plt.scatter(periods[p_peak], density[p_peak])
    plt.text(periods[p_peak], density[p_peak], f"{periods[p_peak]:.1f}  ", ha='right', va='center')
plt.title('periodogram')
plt.show()
```

[image]

We found two main periods

```
period_peaks
[56.888888888888886, 28.444444444444443]
```

If we use the higher density period (56.9, the fundamental, or 1st harmonic) we miss a peak

```
peaks = find_peaks(Y, distance=period_peaks[0])[0]
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.plot(X[peaks], Y[peaks], marker='o', ls='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This could be because

- you have too few observations
- the periodicity is not constant

If we empirically subtract a quantity (say 10) from the period, we find all the peaks

```
peaks = find_peaks(Y, distance=period_peaks[0] - 10)[0]
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.plot(X[peaks], Y[peaks], marker='o', ls='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

So we got peaks at

```
X[peaks]
array([  7,  61, 118, 174])
```

taking the difference, we see they're not regular (at this sample rate and with these few observations)

```
np.diff(X[peaks])
array([54, 57, 56])
```